# Chrome extension effect on page load time

Tags: performance, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm writing a Chrome extension and I want to measure how it affects performance, specifically currently I'm interested in how it affects page load times.

I picked a certain page I want to test, recorded it with Fiddler and I use this recording as the AutoResponder in Fiddler. This allows me to measure load times without networking traffic delays.

Using this technique I found out that my extension adds ~1200ms to the load time. Now I'm trying to figure out what causes the delay and I'm having trouble understanding the DevTools Performance results.

First of all, it seems there's a discrepancy in the reported load time:
On one hand, the summary shows a range of ~13s, but on the other hand, the load event arrived after ~10s (which I also corroborated using `performance.timing.loadEventEnd - performance.timing.navigationStart`):

[image: Unclear load times]

The second thing I don't quite understand is how the number add up (or rather don't add up). For example, here's a grouping of different categories during load:

[image]

Neither of this columns sums up to 10s nor to 13s.

When I group by domain I can get different rows for the extension and for the rest of the stuff:

[image]

But it seems that the extension only adds 250ms which is much lower than the exhibited difference in load times.

I assume that these numbers represent just CPU time, and do not include any wait time. Is this correct? If so, it's OK that the numbers don't add up and it's possible that the extension doesn't spend all its time doing CPU bound work.

Then there's also the mysterious [Chrome extensions overhead], which doesn't explain the difference in load times either. Judging by the fact that it's a separate line from my extension, I thought they are mutually exclusive, but if I dive deeper into the specifics, I find my extension's functions under the [Chrome extensions overhead] subdomain:

[image]

So to summarize, this is what I want to be able to do:

- Calculate the total CPU time my extension uses - it seems it's not enough to look under the extension's name, and its functions might also appear in other groups.
- Understand whether the delay in load time is caused by CPU processing or by synchronous waiting. If it's the latter, find where my extension is doing a synchronous wait, because I'm pretty sure that I didn't call any blocking APIs.

**Update**

Eventually I found out that the reason for the slowdown was that we also activated Chrome accessibility whenever our extension was running and that's what caused the drastic slowdown. Without accessibility the extension had a very minor effect. I still wonder though, how I could see in the profiler that my problem was the accessibility. It could have saved me a ton of time... I will try to look at it again later.

Comment: "Bottom-up" panel shows only the CPU time. Self time means the code inside the function, total = self + all other functions invoked by this one. Depending on what *actually* does your extension there are various methods of slowing down page load process. For example, it may be adding slow external stuff into the request queue. Try comparing two flame charts with and without your extension.